# Pytorch - mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (3328x13 and 9216x4096)

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, tensor

I'm a beginner to pytorch and I'm trying to extract activations from 7 layers for the pre-trained alexnet model. Getting this error when trying to extract activations from the fc6 layer:

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmM1c.png)

Here is my code for looping over my array of images and attempting to extract the activations.

```
    conv1 = alexnet.features[0:2](img_tensor)
    conv2 = alexnet.features[2:5](conv1)
    conv3 = alexnet.features[5:7](conv2)
    conv4 = alexnet.features[7:9](conv3)
    conv5 = alexnet.features[9:12](conv4)
    fc6 = alexnet.classifier[0:2](conv5)
    fc7 = alexnet.classifier[0:2](fc6)
```

I am applying the following transform to each image

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(
        mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
        std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
    )
])
```

From what I understand I need to resize the conv5 layer before multiplying it with the alexnet classifier but I'm not too sure what an effective way to do that is.

Appreciate any help with resolving this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to flatten it. You can do it easily with:
**conv5 = conv5.flatten(1)**

Although I don't know why you were applying 2 layers by 2 layers. I guess you were just learning. You could apply all at a time you know.

Edit:
I detected you have another mistake, here `conv5 = alexnet.features[9:12](conv4)` it should be `conv5 = alexnet.features[9:](conv4)` remember that the right is exclusive. And `fc7 = alexnet.classifier[0:2](fc6)` I guess you mean `fc7 = alexnet.classifier[2:4](fc6)`.